# как и в каком контексте используется OWL и RDF

Tags: веб-программирование

Читаю лекции про онтологию. здесь упоминается про язык описания онтологии, [OWL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language). Я не совсем понимаю, как, когда и в каком контексте он используется.

для чего нужен OWL?
есть ли проэкты в которых можно посмотреть применение OWL в коде?
что связывает OWL с RDF?